# Use Variable In LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, load-data-infile

I've been working on a script that will import data from a CSV file to phpMyAdmin database table.

Using this code was working ok:

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
     INTO TABLE c170720
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
     OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (ccode,custarea,ttlpkt)
eof;
```

But if I use this, it doesn't work:

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
     INTO TABLE '$m_cfile'
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
     OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (ccode,custarea,ttlpkt)
    eof;
```

This is the entire code:

```
<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$password   = "";
$db         = "smposf";

$con        = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$message = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) 
{
   $m_date=date($sdate);
   $m_yy=substr($m_date,2,2);
   $m_mm=substr($m_date,5,2);
   $m_dd=substr($m_date,8,2);

   $m_cfile='c'.$m_yy.$m_mm.$m_dd;

   $allowed = array('csv');
   $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) 
   {
    // show error message       
      $message = 'Invalid file type, please use .CSV file!';
   } 
   else 
   {

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "CSV/" . 
       $_FILES['file']['name']);

       $file = "CSV/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

       $query = <<<eof
                   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
                   INTO TABLE '$m_cfile'
                   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                   OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '"'
                   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                   IGNORE 1 LINES
                   (ccode,custarea,ttlpkt)
        eof;

        if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) 
        {
             exit(mysqli_error($con));
        }
        $message = "CSV file successfully imported!";
    }
}
?>
```

If I use

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
                       INTO TABLE c170720
                       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                       OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '"'
                       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                       IGNORE 1 LINES
                       (ccode,custarea,ttlpkt)`

it works totally fine, but I need variable `$m_cfile`. This is because the user will create a file per day with a specific date. What is wrong?

Comment: Hi, are $m_cfile tables created somewhere else, and what do you mean by "it works totally fine, but I need variable" ??

Comment: @Lambda7 Hi, Ops! I put the wrong script there. I'll edit it. Hold on.

Comment: @Lambda7 Done edit. The `$m_cfile` table is created on another page. I write it there just to show how `$m_cfile` is created.

Comment: You are trying to generate query using heredoc, it will be much convenient to create query inside a double quoted string.

Comment: @RajatJain U mean like this: `$query = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE c170720 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY ' " ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (ccode,custarea,ttlpkt)";` ?

Comment: Yes, alaways use double quoted string if you want to use variables inside it

Comment: @RajatJain I've tried but `'\n'` the colour won't change..`'\n'` stays in black colour in Notepad++ ... How can I fix it? I've checked whether all the quotes have been closed correctly

Comment: I'd say rather check if $m_cfile holds existing table names and then check all the columns and their descriptions to see if they fit

Comment: @Lambda7 Checked and the columns and descriptions are fit...

Comment: then, print your query, before the statement `exit(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: I m not sure about notepad++. You must use an IDE like Netbeans or PhpStorm for Php development.

Comment: @Lambda7 Done echo the query. But show this error message : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''c170720' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ' at line 2`

Comment: @Lambda7 I've solved the error. It should be `INTO TABLE $m_cfile` instead i wrote `INTO TABLE '$m_cfile'`.

Comment: Good for you, write your answer, and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Change `INTO TABLE '$m_cfile'` to `INTO TABLE $m_cfile`